# Multiple View Components in a hybrid Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, view-components

Is it possible to have more than one view component in an asp.net core Hybrid controller, like child actions in .Net framework MVC? and if yes what naming can they have?

Comment: Could you explain more details about what you want to achieve? Your question is not very clear.